# why is this mysql query returns empty result

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, parameters

this function is meant to return doctor's information from tow separate tables doctor and clinic

```
function searchSubs($spc, $stt, $name, $ls, $ll){
    $query ='
        SELECT doctor.*, clinic.address
        FROM doctor
        LEFT JOIN clinic
            ON ( doctor.id = clinic.dr <<STATE CONDITION>>)
        WHERE doctor.dr_name REGEXP  :dr <<SPECIALIZATION CONDITION>>
            AND doctor.active = 1
        LIMIT :s, :l;
        '
    ;

    $query = ($spc == 0) ? str_replace('<<SPECIALIZATION CONDITION>>','',$query): str_replace('<<SPECIALIZATION CONDITION>>',' AND `doctor`.`specialization` = :sp ',$query);
    $query = ($stt == 0) ? str_replace('<<STATE CONDITION>>','',$query): str_replace('<<STATE CONDITION>>',' AND `clinic`.`governorate` = :st ',$query);

    $searchPDO = new PDO(DNS,ReaderUser,ReaderPass);
    $searchPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $searchPDO->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    $stmt = $searchPDO->prepare($query);

    if ($spc != 0) $stmt->bindParam(":sp",$spc,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($stt != 0) $stmt->bindParam(":st",$stt,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(":dr",'.*'.$name.'.*',PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":s",$ls,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":l",$ll,PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    $Drs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $Drs;
}
```

it works fine when i call the function like that:

```
$drs = searchSubs('12', 6, '<<some Arabic name here>>' , 0, 10);
```

and it does not when i call it like that:

```
$SDrs = searchSubs($specialization,$state,$name,$s,$l);
```

i've spent the last 2 days searching for the reason of that but nothing ,
i've url_decoded the string variable `$name` tried many different ways with datatypes in the data base but nothing too,

Comment: what is in those variables `$specialization,$state,$name,$s,$l`?

Comment: Did you try with `$searchPDO->exec("SET NAMES utf8");`?

Comment: It could be character encoding of your page, so you need to utf8_encode it. Normally you would also do a url_decoding before searching a database, rather than encoding. And then it would be a good idea to replace mostly all of your variable names so your code becomes readable.

Comment: Please debug with `echo $query` to see what the constructed query looks like!

Comment: this variable 
`$specialization` contains an integer value of dr's specialization
`$state` contains an integer value of clinic address state
`$name` contains a string value of dr's name in Arabic
`$s` and `$l` contains an integer value for LIMIT statement

Comment: when i search with only 1 letter it results and fetches but when using more letters it is hopeless

Comment: i've used `$searchPDO->exec("SET NAMES utf8");` it's the same url_decoded the name it's the same

Comment: Have you tried to echo the PDO error information? `die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo()));` after the execution

Comment: i've put the error mode to warning so that all resulting errors will be displayed

Comment: Yes, the PHP errors, but not the MySql errors. Just try it once, it will take 10 secs, maybe it helps...

Comment: i meant that the pdo::ERR_MODE to PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that. So: no results and no errors?

Comment: yes ... 

i'm trying very hard along three days by now 

and i had to change the query it worked fine now but i still improving it 

`
        SELECT doctor.*, clinic.address FROM doctor ,clinic
        WHERE doctor.dr_name  REGEXP :dr
            AND clinic.dr = doctor.id
            <<SPECIALIZATION CONDITION>>
            <<STATE CONDITION>>
            AND doctor.active = 1
        GROUP BY doctor.id
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT :s, :l;
        '
`